# Targeting the previous variable in for each loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@foreach ($image as $image)

        <div class="col-md-4">

             @if($image->isCompleted == '1')     
                <div class="panel panel-default">
             @else 
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
             @endif

                    <div class="panel-heading">Image Upload {{$loop->iteration}} Title</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    <img id="step-{{$loop->iteration}}-image" src="{{ $image->filename }}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary imgUploadBtn" id="step{{$loop->iteration}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imgUploadModal">Upload Image {{$loop->iteration}}</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

I've made a foreach loop within my blade template which pulls in 6 panels with images. However I'm wondering is it possible when it finishes the first loop and moves onto the second one can I target the previous $image and query its information. eg Check if $image[0] has been completed then my second panel would display default otherwise it would be danger if it wasnt completed. etc

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the previous iteration in a foreach loop, but a possibility could be running a for loop, and at the part where you want the previous loop call array[$i-1] to get the previous loop. Although take care with the first iteration since then you will have a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for instead of foreach to do this, like so:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < images->count(); $i++)
        $image = $images[$i];
        <div class="col-md-4">

             @if($image->isCompleted == '1')     
                <div class="panel panel-default">
             @else 
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
             @endif

                    <div class="panel-heading">Image Upload {{$loop->iteration}} Title</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    <img id="step-{{$loop->iteration}}-image" src="{{ $image->filename }}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary imgUploadBtn" id="step{{$loop->iteration}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imgUploadModal">Upload Image {{$loop->iteration}}</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
@endfor
```

Now to access the previous image, use `$images[$i - 1]`